# A good way to decode transaction hash content on public Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, hash

I want to check if there are some good tools available to decode the transaction hash to know the content on public Ethereum Blockchain? Primarily to validate the data stored by the dapp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't decode a hash. Hashes are one-way functions and the whole point of them is that you can't reverse them.

So any validation you want to do has to be done by using the (assumed to be) same input and checking whether it produces the right output hash.